# How to get CallbackQuery from an inline button with url?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I defined a keyboard:

```
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard=[
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text=MOVIE_WATCH_BTN, callback_data=MOVIE_WATCH_CB, url=VIEWING_LINK)
        ]
    ]
)
```

now I want to catch the moment of pressing this button:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text=[MOVIE_WATCH_CB])
async def process_movie_watch(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    pass
```

but this method is never called when I press this button in telegram. Then I've tried to use a method like this:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: True)
async def inline_checkout(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    pass
```

and it's not called, too. Although other buttons without links work properly. It seems like the problem is with the link, maybe there are some other ways to catch the the moment of pressing buttons with links?

Here is the whole code:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram import types
from aiogram import executor
from aiogram.types import (
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, 
    InlineKeyboardButton
)

bot = Bot(token="BotToken")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

watch_cb = "watch_cb"
second_cb = "second_cb"

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("The bot is started!", reply_markup=get_inline_keyboard())

def get_inline_keyboard():
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                inline_keyboard=[
                    [
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text="Watch", callback_data=watch_cb, url="https://google.com"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text="Second Button", callback_data=second_cb)
                    ]
                ]
            )

@dp.callback_query_handler(text=watch_cb)
async def process_watch_btn(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    print("\ncall = process_watch_btn()\n")


@dp.callback_query_handler(text=second_cb)
async def process_second_btn(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    print("\ncall = process_second_btn()\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData

cb_inline = CallbackData("post", 'action', "data")
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard= [
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='MyText', callback_data=cb_inline.new(action='myact', data='MyText')
        ]
    )
```

And:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(cb_inline.filter(action='myact'))
async def choice_registr_method(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data):
    pass
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: I need more the code

Comment: It`s impossible. [Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton:~:text=This%20object%20represents%20one%20button%20of%20an%20inline%20keyboard.%20You%20must%20use%20exactly%20one%20of%20the%20optional%20fields.). You have to find another way